# Why are the role of the parentheses in this .reduce() syntax which creates a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reduce

The following code shows three uses of JavaScript `.reduce()`:

1. add up a sum
2. build an array
3. build a JavaScript object

How does one understand the added parentheses around the braces in the third example? Are they just there so that the object-braces are not interpreted as function-braces? Or do they have some other purpose?

Is there another way to write the third example so that this syntax is more explicit, e.g. could one build the JavaScript object within a multiline function somehow?

```
const languages = ['french', 'french', 'spanish', 'polish', 'spanish', 'german', 'spanish', 'polish', 'spanish', 'spanish', 'french', 'spanish', 'english', 'french', 'spanish', 'english', 'french', 'english'];

// 1. iterating while adding a sum
const sum = languages.reduce((acc, language) => {
    acc++;
    return acc;
}, 0);
console.log(`There are ${sum} entries.`);

// 2. iterating while building an array
const initials = languages.reduce((acc, language) => {
    acc.push(language.substring(0, 1));
    return acc;
}, []);
console.log(initials);

// 3. iterating while building a JavaScript object
const totals = languages.reduce((acc, language) => ({
    ...acc,
    [language]: acc[language] ? acc[language] + 1 : 1
}), {});
console.log(totals);
```

Comment: It's an arrow function shortcut syntax for returning an object.

Comment: To prevent the brackets from being interpreted as a code block instead of an object literal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes they are there to prevent the brackets from being readed as frunction-braces because:

```
.reduce((acc,language) => acc)
```

Without curly braces the arrow function will return whats on the right side. Its the equivalent to this here:

```
.reduce((acc,language) => { return acc })
```

In case you want to return an object `{}` you cant simply use curly braces they would be interpreted as function-braces so you would need to wrap them in parenthesis

```
.reduce((acc,language) => ({...acc})
```

And this is the equivalent to:

```
.reduce((acc,langauge) => {
   return {...acc};
})
```